# WebView onLoadingChanged on Android (QML, Qt 5.5)

Tags: android, qml, qt5

Trying to port some easy code to Android:

```
import QtQuick 2.4
import QtQuick.Controls 1.4
import QtWebView 1.0
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.1
import QtGraphicalEffects 1.0
import QtMultimedia 5.4

Item {
    id: root
    WebView {
        id: webView
        url: "http://www.stackoverflow.com"
        anchors.fill: root
        onLoadingChanged: {
            console.log("onLoadingChanged called.");
        }
    }

    BusyIndicator {
        running: webView.loading
        anchors.centerIn: webView
    }
}
```

This code DOESN'T work on Android. If I remove onLoadingChanged method, everything works and page will be shown. The code bellow works fine on Windows.
I made some "3rd leg" for my app, but if onLoadingChanged will work on Android or somebody give me a hint, that would be great.